# ttk.Combobox: is it possible to change font on individual items?

Tags: python-2.7, ttk

I would like to change the font of certain items in a Combobox, to indicate that the option can't be selected for the moment. Is that possible? Alternative solutions, such as changing the background color to gray or so would work too. I imagine something similar to modifying items in a tk Listbox

```
lb.itemconfig(0, {'bg':'red'}) # set red as background color for first item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to customize individual items in a combobox.